# Rotate video, output maximum 1920 x 1080 pixels

Tags: ffmpeg

I used

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 310 -i "H:\_REC\100MEDIA\someavi.AVI" -ss 0 -t 14 -vf "rotate='54*PI/180:ow=hypot(iw,ih):oh=ow'" -vf scale=1920:1080 "H:\_REC\100MEDIA\somemp4.mp4"
```

which should rotate the video(currently 1920 x 1080, MJPEG, 30fps) around 54° and fit it into 1920 x 1080 Pixels.

What it does is, it ignores the `-vf "rotate='54*PI/180:ow=hypot(iw,ih):oh=ow'" -vf scale=1920:1080` and returns the snippet.

What to change?

PS: ffmpeg version N-59696-gc0a33c4

OUTPUT:

```
E:\Ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -ss 310 -i "H:\_REC\100MEDIA\someavi.AVI"
 -ss 0 -t 14 -vf "rotate='54*PI/180:ow=hypot(iw,ih):oh=ow'" -vf sca
le=1920:1080 "H:\_REC\100MEDIA\somemp4.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-59696-gc0a33c4 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  8 2014 22:07:06 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 62.100 / 52. 62.100
  libavcodec     55. 47.100 / 55. 47.100
  libavformat    55. 22.102 / 55. 22.102
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     4.  0.103 /  4.  0.103
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[avi @ 0000000002858060] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'H:\_REC\100MEDIA\someavi.AVI':
  Duration: 00:19:59.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13866 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080, 30 t
br, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 1
28 kb/s
File 'H:\_REC\100MEDIA\somemp4.mp4' already exists.
Overwrite ? [y/N] y
No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] 264 - core 140 r2377 1ca7bb9 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 dec
imate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b
_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=
25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.
60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'H:\_REC\100MEDIA\somemp4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.22.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p, 1920x
1080, q=-1--1, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 8000 Hz, mo
no, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   30 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.82 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s
frame=   55 fps= 54 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.59 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s
frame=   75 fps= 46 q=29.0 size=     600kB time=00:00:02.10 bitrate=2337.0kbits/
frame=   90 fps= 41 q=29.0 size=    1017kB time=00:00:02.61 bitrate=3185.9kbits/
frame=  105 fps= 37 q=29.0 size=    1482kB time=00:00:03.12 bitrate=3881.8kbits/
frame=  120 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    1959kB time=00:00:03.76 bitrate=4258.3kbits/
frame=  140 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=    2588kB time=00:00:04.28 bitrate=4953.2kbits/
frame=  145 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=    2742kB time=00:00:04.66 bitrate=4816.0kbits/
frame=  162 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=    3274kB time=00:00:05.17 bitrate=5181.6kbits/
frame=  177 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=    3744kB time=00:00:05.56 bitrate=5515.8kbits/
frame=  190 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=    4144kB time=00:00:06.07 bitrate=5591.5kbits/
frame=  205 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=    4612kB time=00:00:06.45 bitrate=5851.7kbits/
frame=  215 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    4895kB time=00:00:06.96 bitrate=5754.9kbits/
frame=  227 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    5169kB time=00:00:07.35 bitrate=5759.4kbits/
frame=  245 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    5571kB time=00:00:07.99 bitrate=5710.1kbits/
frame=  262 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    6052kB time=00:00:08.50 bitrate=5830.4kbits/
frame=  280 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    6505kB time=00:00:09.14 bitrate=5827.4kbits/
frame=  300 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    7048kB time=00:00:09.65 bitrate=5979.4kbits/
frame=  305 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    7175kB time=00:00:09.91 bitrate=5930.2kbits/
frame=  322 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    7675kB time=00:00:10.55 bitrate=5958.3kbits/
frame=  342 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    8237kB time=00:00:11.06 bitrate=6098.9kbits/
frame=  357 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    8661kB time=00:00:11.70 bitrate=6062.0kbits/
frame=  369 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    9010kB time=00:00:12.08 bitrate=6105.8kbits/
frame=  387 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    9501kB time=00:00:12.72 bitrate=6115.2kbits/
frame=  407 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=   10052kB time=00:00:13.24 bitrate=6219.2kbits/
frame=  414 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=   10257kB time=00:00:13.62 bitrate=6167.7kbits/
frame=  421 fps= 26 q=-1.0 Lsize=   12062kB time=00:00:14.00 bitrate=7053.8kbits
/s dup=253 drop=0
video:12036kB audio:19kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.054462%

[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] frame I:2     Avg QP:21.20  size:106302
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] frame P:336   Avg QP:23.51  size: 36006
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] frame B:83    Avg QP:23.96  size:   169
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] consecutive B-frames: 60.6% 39.4%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] mb I  I16..4:  2.0% 96.2%  1.8%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] mb P  I16..4:  0.6% 31.1%  0.1%  P16..4: 13.6%  3.3
%  1.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:49.8%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.3%  0.0
%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.7%  L0: 1.5% L1:98.5% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] 8x8 transform intra:97.7% inter:79.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 86.0% 87.6% 8.9% inter: 9.
3% 15.7% 1.4%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] i16 v,h,dc,p:  7%  7%  6% 80%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 14% 54%  3%  3%
 2%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 12% 14%  6% 21%
 5% 19%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 24% 25%  3%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] Weighted P-Frames: Y:3.6% UV:3.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] ref P L0: 57.9% 15.5%  9.5% 16.4%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] ref B L0: 34.6% 65.4%
[libx264 @ 00000000049f2980] kb/s:7025.99
```

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Output added

Comment: @LordNeckbeard See https://superuser.com/questions/739834/rotate-video-output-maximum-1920-x-1080-pixels